# How to create Shared Buffer on Vulkan Host Program?

Tags: glsl, shader, vulkan

1. Goal 
   I want to set 'shared' buffer's size in GLSL on runtime.

Question is "How to create shared memory in Vulkan Host C/C++ program?" \

2. Example
   In OpenCL, below OpenCL Kernel function has '__local' argument.

```
// foo.cl
__kernel void foo(__global float *dst, __global float *src, __local *buf ){
   /*do something great*/
}
```

and in host C++ program, I create __local memory and pass it kernel args.

```
void main(){
    ...
    cl_uint args_index = 2;
    foo.setArg(args_index,__local(128) ); // make 128bytes local memory and pass it to kernel.
}
```

I want to do same thing on Vulkan Compute Pipeline.
and I tried below.

3. GLSL

```
//foo.comp
#version 450
layout(binding=0) buffer dstBuffer{
   uint dst[];
};
layout(binding=1) buffer srcBuffer{
   uint src[];
};
```

```
// try 1
layout(binding=2) uniform SharedMemSize{
   uint size[];
};
shared uint buf[size[0]]; // compile Error! msg : array size must be a constant integer expression
```

```
// try 2
layout(binding=2) shared SharedBuffer{
   uint buf[]; 
}; // compile Error! msg :'shared block' not supported
```

```
//try 3
layout(binding=2) shared uint buf[]; // compile Error! msg : binding requires uniform or buffer.
```

I failed above things. 
need your help. thanks.

Comment: What is a "shared buffer"?

Comment: @NicolBolas It is a memory type that can be accessed by threads in same workgroup(in OpenCL), block(in CUDA)

Comment: You can find the answer [here.](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/10653/2654)

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh... thanks... it's impossible.  would you please write it answer? then i will adopt it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLSL has `shared` variables, which [represent storage accessible to any member of a work group](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader#Shared_variables). However, it doesn't have "shared memory" in the same way as OpenCL. You cannot directly upload data to `shared` variables from the CPU, for example. You can't get a pointer to `shared` variables.

The closest you might get to this is to have some kind of shared variable array whose size is determined from outside of the shader. But even then, you're not influencing the size of memory in total; you're influencing the size of just that *array*.

And you can sort of do that. [SPIR-V in OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/SPIR-V) allows specialization constants. These are values specified by the outside world during the compilation process for the shader object. Such constants can be used as the size for a shared variable array. Of course, this means that changing it requires a full recompile/relink process.